# Why do I need np.array() or np.copy()?

Tags: python, numpy

A real numpy newbie question here.

I have an numpy array called 'image'. Doing this:

```
image2 = image
image2[image < minval] = minval
image2[image > maxval] = maxval
```

...changes the contents of 'image'.

I gather that's because variables in Python are really references, so 'image2' is just another way of referring to 'image'. So I'm supposed to use "image2 = np.copy(image)". Fine.

***But, then, why doesn't 'a' change when I do this:***

```
a = 5
b = a
b = 7
```

Isn't 'b' just another way of referring to 'a'? If so, why doesn't a==7 at the end of this?

I want to know if there's some mental model that makes this seem consistent. Because it doesn't.

Answer (score 5):

The answer really lies in the way direct *assignments* like `b=a` and `b=7` work.  `b=a` creates a new reference to the object also referenced by `a`, and associates that new reference with the name `b`. The subsequent `b=7` then *removes* the reference that was attached to the name `b`, and makes a different association with the name `b`.   This will be true whether `a` is an immutable type (like an integer) or a mutable type (like a numpy array).  In neither case will the content of `a` be modified.

By contrast, `image2[image < minval] = minval` is not a reassignment.  Via its use of `[]` it calls a method (`__setitem__`) of the object `image2`.  This method changes parts of the underlying data structure without reassigning anything to `image2`.

Python's most fundamental types are "immutable".  This means that *nothing* you can do will change them (for example, if `image2` were of the immutable type `tuple`, trying to change one of its elements with `[]` indexing would cause an exception to be raised).

As a result, *very very loosely*, if you're accustomed to a C/C++ mindset, it can sometimes help to think of immutable types as being passed by value and mutable types being passed by reference when you're looking at a function or method prototype.  As pointed out in the comments, though, this is not really what happens: everything is a reference, but some references (the immutable types) are automatically treated the way C/C++ would treat `const` references.

The immutable types include:

- basic numeric types: `bool`, `int`, `long`, `float` and `complex`
- basic string types: `str`, `unicode` (python 2.x only) and `bytes` (python 3.x only)
- `tuple` (but not `list`)

Comment: No, no, no! This is 100% false! Nothing of the sort happens. Assigning a value to a variable *never* makes a copy, no matter what the type of the value is.

Comment: You can test it out in an interactive interpreter. If you do `a = 10000` and `b = 10000`, `a is b` will be `False`, since Python happens to make two separate int objects. However, if you do `b = a`, `a is b` will be `True`. If Python was making a copy, `a` and `b` would be separate objects, and `a is b` would be `False`.

Comment: This answer is deeply misleading as it suggests a distinction which doesn't exist between how variables are treated depending on their mutability.  Worse, it makes Python's behaviour seem complicated and arbitrary, when really it's simplicity itself: *no copies are made*.

Comment: I take your point, (although actually it's more complicated: though `a is b` evaluates to `False` if `a==b==1000`, it evaluates to `True` if `a==b` and their value in the range -5 to 256 since these particular values are singletons).

Comment: I've corrected the answer as best I can. Probably there's still room for improvement.

Comment: @ComputerScientist  i would claim that it has. You can look at the edit history to see the previous versions that the commenters were objecting to.